# does linux kernel 2.6.22 support bluetooth 4.0

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, bluetooth-lowenergy

my project has a hardware with linux kernel 2.6.22 without build-in bluetooth.

recently we want to implement ibeacon so we think it needs bluetooth 4.0 usb dangle.

my question is does linux kernel 2.6.22 support bluetooth 4.0 ?

Because from bluez5.0 website http://lwn.net/Articles/531133/, it says that bluetooth 4.0 is not supported until kernel 3.5 .

so, is it true that without kernel support, we can't just use the bluez5.0 userspace library to control bluetooth4.0 usb dangle?

any feedback is highly appreciated!. Thanks!

Steven Song

Comment: Have you tried it? 2.6 is really old, though, so I guess the libs are probably not backported that far.

Comment: hi, allprog:  no , i haven't tried it yet. Because I check the bluetooth driver code, it is quite different with kernel 3.0 and higher . Some of the driver no longer exist anymore. Anyway , thanks your reply. I will try use my ubuntu with 3.x kernel as ibeacon first.

Comment: Yes, this is the best approach, I agree. Try to get it running with the new version to see what you can expect and then may try to get the old version spinning if needed.